# AnnotationConfigRegistry not found in spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having an strange behavior, using spring 4.1.1 I get this error.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile  (default-compile) on project newvalia-view: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/edu/IdeaProjects/newvalia/newvalia- view/src/main/java/com/newvalia/web/init/WebInitContext.java:[19,12] cannot access org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigRegistry
[ERROR] class file for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigRegistry not found
```

while if I downgrade to spring 4.0.7 it compiles correctly.
I am using simple spring webmwc configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.newvalia.web")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 }

public class WebInitContext implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

    ctx.setServletContext(container);

    Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

}
```

is this a new expected behavior?

Comment: are you importing org.springframework.context jar file ?

Comment: yes,I am just changing spring version in my pom. that's all

Comment: Oh my god, I was pointing a harcoded spring context jar, instead global property in pom.

Answer (score 2):

import `org.springframework.context` jar correctly in your pom file , and thats it .

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 1):

Add spring context dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```